# How to get Directory information via Windows native API?

Tags: windows, winapi, kernel32

I can get the created date, file size etc for a **file** using the following code:

```
// Error handling removed for brevity 
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(path, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, 
             NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL); 

LARGE_INTEGER fileSize; 
GetFileSizeEx(hFile, &fileSize); 

FILE_BASIC_INFO fileInfo); 
GetFileInformationByHandle(hFile, FileBasicInfo, fileInfo, sizeof(fileInfo));
```

But when called against a directory, all values are set to zero - how do I get directory info?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ran into something like this once you have to pass this flag to get a valid handle for a directory.  From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858(VS.85).aspx) documentation.

try this

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(path, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, 
         NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL|FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, NULL);
```

`FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS` | You must set this flag to obtain a handle to a directory. A directory handle can be passed to some functions instead of a file handle. For more information, see the Remarks section.